# How to return nested JSON in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have three different tables.
1. Order details (id, itemId,date,userId)
2. Item details (id, itemName, quantity)
3. User details (id, userName)

I want to return a JSON as:

```
{[
{
 orderId = 1,
 items = [
   {
     itemId = 1,
     itemName = ITEM_DEMO,

},
{
   itemId = 2,
   itemName = ITEM_DEMO2,
}
],
userDetails = {
   userId = 1,
   userName = TEST_USER
}

}

]}
```

How can we do this in Node JS. Im using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read about `object` and `json` in `javascript`.
For parsing your data from `mySql` to `json` do the following steps:

1. Create an object that is filled with your data from `mySql`.

```js
const ArrayObjectFilledWithMysqlData = [
  {
     orderId: 1,
     items: [{
       itemId: 1,
       itemName: ITEM_DEMO,
    },
    {
       itemId: 2,
       itemName: ITEM_DEMO2,
    }]
  },
  {
    userDetails: {
      userId: 1,
      userName: TEST_USER
    }
  }
]
```

2. Parse the Array to `json`.

```js
const jsonFromData = JSON.stringify(ArrayObjectFilledWithMysqlData)
```

Comment: I have nested queries to fetch data. how to manage asynchronous calls.